# Undefined symbol compiler error on imported function prototype but what to define?

Tags: c, stm32, extern, i2c, undefined-symbol

this is probably straight forward but my C is entry level at best. Im interfacing a LIS2DH12 accelerator to STM32L152. Im using a ST driver. My compiling error is `"undefined symbol Sensor_IO_Read"` and `"undefined symbol Sensor_IO_Write"`.

The 2 lines of code its complainging about is as follow

`extern uint8_t Sensor_IO_Read(void *handle, uint8_t ReadAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t nBytesToRead);`

`extern uint8_t Sensor_IO_Write(void *handle, uint8_t WriteAddr, uint8_t *pBuffer, uint16_t nBytesToWrite);`

1. What is expected of me to define? `Sensor_IO_Read/write`, if its a function dont I just declare the function.
2. The `void` inside the function followed by 4 unsigned integers is also unfamiliar to me.

Its an I2C string that requires all the unsigned variables in a particular order 
to be read or written.

Thanks for any explanation

Comment: Seems that you didn't link the library where those functions are located to your project.

Comment: Please post the exact error message as they appear on the display.

Comment: the exact error essage. is as follow :     \Output\SP1ML-915.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol Sensor_IO_Read (referred from lis2dh12_acc_driver.o).
.\Output\SP1ML-915.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol Sensor_IO_Write (referred from lis2dh12_acc_driver.o).

Comment: Yes, linker error, simbols are not available for linker. You should add file with Sensor_IO functions to project to be compiled.

Comment: The .c driver file is added to my project with corresponding .h file. I presume I need to call those two functions from Main to read and write to the sensor. I also presume I need to define `Sensor_IO_Read/write` in main before I can use this driver file

Comment: `undefined symbol [X]` is a linker error. Make sure you either compile and link the resulting object file (if the mentioned functions are compiled by you from source) or that you explicitly link the library that contains those functions (if those functions are located in a library).